# Shiny subset closure error upon deployment

Tags: r, shiny

I'm nearly complete with my Shiny app, but keep running into an error.

Here is the script, for reference:

UI is as follows:

```
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(sqldf)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("mydata", label = "C4 or C3?", choices = c("C4","C3"), inline=TRUE),
      selectizeInput("data1", "Select State", selected = "MI", multiple = TRUE, choices = c(unique(sort(df$state)))),
      selectizeInput("data2", "Select County", choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data3", "Select City", selected = "DETROIT", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
      selectizeInput("data4", "Select Demo", choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$demo)))),
      selectizeInput("data5", "Select Registration Status", choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$registration_status)))),
      selectizeInput("data6", "Valid Address", choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$vb_voterbase_mailable_flag)))),
      sliderInput("age", label = h3("Select Age Range"), 18,
                  35, value = c(18, 20), round = TRUE, step = 1),
      sliderInput("turnout", label = h3("Select Range"), min = 0,
                  max = 100, value = c(20,80)),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.mydata=='C4'",
                       sliderInput("partisan", label = h3("Select Range"), min = 0, max = 100, value = c(20,80))
      ),
      prettyCheckboxGroup("phones", h3("Only Include Valid Phone Numbers?"), selected = "Yes", choices = list("Yes")),
      downloadButton("download", "Download Data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("universecount"),
      tags$head(tags$style("#universecount{color: red;
                                 font-size: 32px;
                                 font-style: italic;
                                 }"
      )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

And now the Server.R file:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  mydf <- reactive({get(input$mydata)})
  observeEvent(input$data1, {
    df <- mydf()
    #if (input$data1 != "All") {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$county[df$state == input$data1]))))
    # } else {
    #   updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$county)))
    # }
  }, priority = 2)
  
  observeEvent(c(input$data1, input$data2), {
    req(mydf())
    df <- mydf()
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$city[df$county == input$data2]))))
    } else {
      #if (input$data1 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$city[df$state == input$data1]))))
      # } else {
      #   updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(df$city)))
      # }
    }
  }, priority = 1)
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    req(input$data3)
    temp_data <- mydf()
    if (input$data1 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$state %in% input$data1, ]
    }
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$county == input$data2, ]
    }
    if (input$data3 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$city %in% input$data3, ]
    }
    if (input$data4 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$demo %in% input$data4, ]
    }
    if (input$data5 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$registration_status %in% input$data5, ]
    }
    if (input$data6 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$vb_voterbase_mailable_flag == input$data, ]
    }
    
    df2 <- temp_data %>% dplyr::filter(age >= input$age[1] &
                                         age <= input$age[2] &
                                         turnout_score >= input$turnout[1] &
                                         turnout_score <= input$turnout[2])
    if (input$mydata=="C4") df2 <- df2 %>% dplyr::filter(partisan_score >= input$partisan[1] & partisan_score <= input$partisan[2])
    
    df3 <- if (is.null(input$phones)) df2 else df2 %>%  dplyr::filter(!is.na(phone))
    
  })
  
  output$universecount <- renderText({
    paste("Universe Size:", nrow(filtered_data()))
  })
  
}
```

If I run it locally, it works totally fine. But the issue is when I push it to my Shiny deployment server.

I get the following messages in my logs:

```
2022-01-19T22:54:48.561849+00:00 shinyapps[5182547]: Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
2022-01-19T22:54:48.569921+00:00 shinyapps[5182547]:   105: sort
```

I have a feeling the error might live in this part of the server side script, but I've tried debugging based on prior answers and keep getting the same issue.

```
 output$universecount <- renderText({
    paste("Universe Size:", nrow(filtered_data()))
  })
```

I'm also not exactly sure what the `105: sort` message means. Are they related?

EDIT: Here is the dput for `df`:

```
structure(list(unique_id = c(36363789L, 18988964L, 16094523L, 
39677134L, 4078215L, 28493633L, 3783112L, 18484012L, 13989489L, 
14328803L, 14309304L, 9348817L, 33081795L, 32954689L, 30115329L, 
17177505L, 34680537L, 13908098L, 5946723L, 6684694L, 28609274L, 
1843719L, 20634959L, 5471321L, 26713947L, 17588681L, 30571179L, 
17325937L, 29977204L, 9818333L, 17183018L, 9779557L, 6048733L, 
18017770L, 21816931L, 5974829L, 16954800L, 38106102L, 5335207L, 
8832897L, 32329461L, 15254291L, 14297262L, 39515748L, 31867131L, 
31508617L, 31820666L, 33267058L, 20008072L, 13527430L), state = c("TX", 
"NC", "MI", "TX", "NV", "TX", "AZ", "MI", "MI", "NC", "MI", "AZ", 
"TX", "TX", "TX", "NC", "TX", "MI", "NV", "MI", "TX", "TX", "PA", 
"MI", "TX", "NC", "TX", "MI", "TX", "WI", "MI", "AZ", "MI", "NC", 
"PA", "MI", "MI", "TX", "NV", "AZ", "TX", "MI", "MI", "TX", "TX", 
"TX", "TX", "TX", "PA", "PA"), city = c("BROWNSVILLE", "BURNSVILLE", 
"PORT AUSTIN", "NEW BRAUNFELS", "NORTH LAS VEGAS", "SAN ANTONIO", 
"ARIZONA CITY", "ROCKFORD", "WARREN", "CHARLOTTE", "PINCKNEY", 
"PHOENIX", "BUDA", "FORT WORTH", "LOCKHART", "MATTHEWS", "SAN ANTONIO", 
"LIVONIA", "LAS VEGAS", "JENISON", "GOLIAD", "CADDO MILLS", "MEADVILLE", 
"BANCROFT", "LITTLE ELM", "ASHEVILLE", "SAN MARCOS", "HAZEL PARK", 
"HOUSTON", "CHIPPEWA FALLS", "SOUTH LYON", "QUEEN CREEK", "WYOMING", 
"GREENSBORO", "FELTON", "CHARLEVOIX", "WATERFORD", "HUMBLE", 
"RENO", "SAN TAN VALLEY", "HOUSTON", "NEW BUFFALO", "PAW PAW", 
"HOUSTON", "ARLINGTON", "AUSTIN", "ARLINGTON", "SCHERTZ", "LANCASTER", 
"SHIPPENSBURG"), county = c("CAMERON", "YANCEY", "HURON", "COMAL", 
"CLARK", "BEXAR", "PINAL", "KENT", "MACOMB", "MECKLENBURG", "LIVINGSTON", 
"MARICOPA", "HAYS", "TARRANT", "CALDWELL", "UNION", "BEXAR", 
"WAYNE", "CLARK", "OTTAWA", "GOLIAD", "HUNT", "CRAWFORD", "SHIAWASSEE", 
"DENTON", "BUNCOMBE", "CALDWELL", "OAKLAND", "HARRIS", "CHIPPEWA", 
"OAKLAND", "MARICOPA", "KENT", "GUILFORD", "YORK", "CHARLEVOIX", 
"OAKLAND", "HARRIS", "WASHOE", "PINAL", "HARRIS", "BERRIEN", 
"VAN BUREN", "HARRIS", "TARRANT", "TRAVIS", "TARRANT", "GUADALUPE", 
"LANCASTER", "CUMBERLAND"), age = c(34L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 26L, 
26L, 30L, 18L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 30L, 34L, 30L, 28L, 
29L, 35L, 27L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 27L, 20L, 24L, 34L, 35L, 26L, 20L, 
24L, 31L, 23L, 21L, 31L, 31L, 20L, 33L, 25L, 32L, 27L, 24L, 19L, 
31L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 23L, 35L), demo = c("Hispanic", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "African-American", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", 
"Uncoded", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Uncoded", "African-American", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"African-American", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Uncoded", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", "African-American", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian"), turnout_score = c(5.9, 
54.1, 3.6, 18.4, 1.5, 6.5, 28.3, 21.4, 88.7, 35.4, 20.4, 70.8, 
65, 5.8, 17.5, 4.4, 23.1, 81.8, 45.5, 63.3, 3.8, 32.4, 31.4, 
89.4, 8.8, 9.1, 3.2, 12.6, 48.5, 24.7, 68.1, 2.9, 23.6, 50, 10.5, 
72.3, 83.8, 16.9, 29.5, 20.2, 4.6, 46.9, 65.9, 14.1, 8, 2.5, 
20.5, 39, 22.6, 52.6), partisan_score = c(44.4, 1.4, 23.3, 32.7, 
91.6, 80, 21.3, 6.9, 66.9, 2.3, 62.5, 99, 12.2, 68, 73.2, 2.2, 
92.9, 68.4, 84.6, 10.8, 34.1, 14.7, 0.7, 2, 16.4, 5.5, 87.8, 
71.8, 99.7, 18.7, 75.4, 6.9, 84.7, 98.5, 12.3, 1.9, 62.9, 69.9, 
1.5, 6.9, 34.5, 42.4, 30.2, 34, 54.6, 88.9, 44.7, 71.5, 98.6, 
0.6), first_name = c("firstname1", "firstname2", "firstname3", 
"firstname4", "firstname5", "firstname6", "firstname7", "firstname8", 
"firstname9", "firstname10", "firstname11", "firstname12", "firstname13", 
"firstname14", "firstname15", "firstname16", "firstname17", "firstname18", 
"firstname19", "firstname20", "firstname21", "firstname22", "firstname23", 
"firstname24", "firstname25", "firstname26", "firstname27", "firstname28", 
"firstname29", "firstname30", "firstname31", "firstname32", "firstname33", 
"firstname34", "firstname35", "firstname36", "firstname37", "firstname38", 
"firstname39", "firstname40", "firstname41", "firstname42", "firstname43", 
"firstname44", "firstname45", "firstname46", "firstname47", "firstname48", 
"firstname49", "firstname50"), last_name = c("lastname1", "lastname2", 
"lastname3", "lastname4", "lastname5", "lastname6", "lastname7", 
"lastname8", "lastname9", "lastname10", "lastname11", "lastname12", 
"lastname13", "lastname14", "lastname15", "lastname16", "lastname17", 
"lastname18", "lastname19", "lastname20", "lastname21", "lastname22", 
"lastname23", "lastname24", "lastname25", "lastname26", "lastname27", 
"lastname28", "lastname29", "lastname30", "lastname31", "lastname32", 
"lastname33", "lastname34", "lastname35", "lastname36", "lastname37", 
"lastname38", "lastname39", "lastname40", "lastname41", "lastname42", 
"lastname43", "lastname44", "lastname45", "lastname46", "lastname47", 
"lastname48", "lastname49", "lastname50"), phone = 1234567890:1234567939, 
    registration_status = c("Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
    "Registered", "Registered"), vb_tsmart_full_address = c("1 Fake St", 
    "2 Fake St", "3 Fake St", "4 Fake St", "5 Fake St", "6 Fake St", 
    "7 Fake St", "8 Fake St", "9 Fake St", "10 Fake St", "11 Fake St", 
    "12 Fake St", "13 Fake St", "14 Fake St", "15 Fake St", "16 Fake St", 
    "17 Fake St", "18 Fake St", "19 Fake St", "20 Fake St", "21 Fake St", 
    "22 Fake St", "23 Fake St", "24 Fake St", "25 Fake St", "26 Fake St", 
    "27 Fake St", "28 Fake St", "29 Fake St", "30 Fake St", "31 Fake St", 
    "32 Fake St", "33 Fake St", "34 Fake St", "35 Fake St", "36 Fake St", 
    "37 Fake St", "38 Fake St", "39 Fake St", "40 Fake St", "41 Fake St", 
    "42 Fake St", "43 Fake St", "44 Fake St", "45 Fake St", "46 Fake St", 
    "47 Fake St", "48 Fake St", "49 Fake St", "50 Fake St"), 
    vb_voterbase_mailable_flag = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

Comment: In `unique(sort(df$county[df$state == input$data1]))` it may be better to use `%in%`  instead of `==` as you have `multiple = TRUE` for `input$data1`.

Comment: Is that what might cause closure subset issue?

Comment: @YBS just made your correction. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please post some sample data for c3 and c4 objects, so I can test it.

Comment: @YBS - Just posted a `dput` for `df`. If you look at my code, there is no difference between C3 and C4. It all comes from the same df. The difference is in what features can and can't be selected. When the C3 radio button is toggled on, it does not allow you to select one of the score ranges. You can also just use the same df set if you need to test something out, it's all the same fields. But if you're not seeing this in my script, please point out to where I'm not providing the data. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789199/shiny-app-works-locally-but-produces-error-upon-deployment/70791959?noredirect=1#comment125151365_70791959) applies to this question.  It appears to be the same question.